# check a string for a substring where the end of the string loops around to the start

Tags: python, python-2.7

So let's say I have a string, '*string*', and I know the length of the string, '*length*'. I want to check if a word of the same length, '*checkfor*', is inside *string*.
I know that to do this I can use:

```
if(string[0:length-1]==checkfor):
   Return True
```

but I also want to check if the string is just wrongly positioned, for example let's say *checkfor*=iwantpie which is *length*=8. I want to return True if *string* is 'iwantpie' or 'wantpiei' or 'antpieiw' etc.
I know I could use a statement like:

```
if((string[0:length-1] or string[length-1]+string[0:length-2] or string[length-2:length-1]+string[0:length-3] or ... or string[length-length:length-1])==checkfor):
   Return True
```

where ... is representing repeating that same pattern. It's like making the string circular and checking for a substring.
Obviously this becomes cumbersome as length becomes larger.
Is there a way to consolidate maybe with a for loop?

Writing this I found a possible solution but it's probably not the best and if there's a for loop solution I'd like to see it regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
>>> def checkOccurence(string, checkfor):
...     for i in range(len(string)):
...             if  string[i:]+string[:i] == checkfor:
...                     return True
...     return False
...
```

**Test**

```
>>> string = "antpieiw"
>>> checkfor = "iwantpie"
>>> checkOccurence(string, checkfor)
True

>>> checkfor = "iwantpie234"
>>> checkOccurenct(string, checkfor)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Make *string*=*string*+*string* and then check for *checkfor* as a substring. There are a lot of questions on parsing for substrings already answered so I'll leave you to find those.

Comment: Why are you talking to yourself as if you weren't yourself?

Comment: The last line of my question was originally in this answer but I decided to move it to the question to make this answer neater. Didn't really think about grammar and subject when I moved it.